# How to filter nested array of object?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with filtering a nested array of objects. My expected result, I want to get a user who has an email address that starts with the `mil` (*example*) letter or I want to get user who has `female` gender. I have seen tricks from another question but I still don't get my expected result.

Let's say my data is below:

```js
let users = [{
    "results": [{
        "gender": "female",
        "name": {
          "title": "Miss",
          "first": "Britney",
          "last": "Sims"
        },
        "email": "britney.sims@example.com",
        "login": {
          "uuid": "2d5afd5e-a598-469f-9933-4edba18bcefb",
          "username": "blueelephant921",
          "password": "ccccccc",
          "salt": "uJHyJ9ZL",
          "md5": "5724c4fbd97e5155d19f71a44f12cc48",
          "sha1": "85dff52890cee9977409fc6ae332a7e2326d6aa4",
          "sha256": "ab62d511f943bfca48935cb4620b3b2007f8d1b9c1e04a04ea76ea95cd099d5f"
        },
        "registered": {
          "date": "2014-05-20T20:54:39.692Z",
          "age": 8
        }
      },
      {
        "gender": "female",
        "name": {
          "title": "Ms",
          "first": "Imogen",
          "last": "Edwards"
        },
        "email": "imogen.edwards@example.com",
        "login": {
          "uuid": "5a79ebec-08a6-45de-a2de-b3222f0d1ffe",
          "username": "silversnake277",
          "password": "clifford",
          "salt": "7d1g093S",
          "md5": "585e4a480fb97e0f7430ace6acaabd4f",
          "sha1": "c2214f29692ca2aea5898f7c9e40846e125c5657",
          "sha256": "6ec460f8cbc394e7758f22bbe185c5ae54048e1924fad1b94ac2511511ec2b5a"
        },
        "registered": {
          "date": "2016-04-10T14:57:49.011Z",
          "age": 6
        }
      }
    ],
    "info": {
      "seed": "foobar",
      "results": 10,
      "page": 1,
      "version": "1.3"
    }
  },
  {
    "results": [{
        "gender": "female",
        "name": {
          "title": "Miss",
          "first": "Avery",
          "last": "Harris"
        },
        "email": "avery.harris@example.com",
        "login": {
          "uuid": "36213f8d-ab68-4906-b215-5660c84ffbf2",
          "username": "greengoose482",
          "password": "amazon",
          "salt": "SAFLaz7k",
          "md5": "99b57bab46e91f99e28f9920a70789db",
          "sha1": "ed0faee69842302e732f92f6d06f44d97f3c617e",
          "sha256": "ebcccbab0ce22a2ee5f5caa0f88abbbc58e1fc89829bf30ebfe81b839c0aca1a"
        },
        "registered": {
          "date": "2002-05-16T09:53:41.802Z",
          "age": 20
        }
      },
      {
        "gender": "male",
        "name": {
          "title": "Mr",
          "first": "Milton",
          "last": "Miles"
        },
        "email": "milton.miles@example.com",
        "login": {
          "uuid": "b16bf03e-daa8-46b9-8c8c-6fe605abaa63",
          "username": "brownpanda533",
          "password": "gggg",
          "salt": "4zdtNQQO",
          "md5": "5415ef33797665bc91103cc28e10c127",
          "sha1": "00816e03d999d456524abf9a3f1229d930c2ca37",
          "sha256": "da3db1d7fe779b4c2c5ceebefa60c43a2d5eacb0a31ed8305b52859db82a100d"
        },
        "registered": {
          "date": "2012-02-11T18:46:12.048Z",
          "age": 10
        }
      }
    ],
    "info": {
      "seed": "foobar",
      "results": 10,
      "page": 2,
      "version": "1.3"
    }
  }
]

const findUser = users.filter((u) =>
  u.results.some((i) => i.email.startsWith("mil"))
);
console.log(findUser);
```

From my current code, I just have the data as is.

Comment: Do you want a single user or all who match? Do you only want `gender: female` if there are no matches for `email: mil...`?

Comment: @DM Who all match. Possibly I want add more than one criteria.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get *users*, then `filter` alone isn't quite the right approach, because then you'll get an array of arrays of users, not an array of users. First flatten all the `results` into a single array, then filter *that* array (which is now composed of users).

```js
let users=[{results:[{gender:"female",name:{title:"Miss",first:"Britney",last:"Sims"},email:"britney.sims@example.com",login:{uuid:"2d5afd5e-a598-469f-9933-4edba18bcefb",username:"blueelephant921",password:"ccccccc",salt:"uJHyJ9ZL",md5:"5724c4fbd97e5155d19f71a44f12cc48",sha1:"85dff52890cee9977409fc6ae332a7e2326d6aa4",sha256:"ab62d511f943bfca48935cb4620b3b2007f8d1b9c1e04a04ea76ea95cd099d5f"},registered:{date:"2014-05-20T20:54:39.692Z",age:8}},{gender:"female",name:{title:"Ms",first:"Imogen",last:"Edwards"},email:"imogen.edwards@example.com",login:{uuid:"5a79ebec-08a6-45de-a2de-b3222f0d1ffe",username:"silversnake277",password:"clifford",salt:"7d1g093S",md5:"585e4a480fb97e0f7430ace6acaabd4f",sha1:"c2214f29692ca2aea5898f7c9e40846e125c5657",sha256:"6ec460f8cbc394e7758f22bbe185c5ae54048e1924fad1b94ac2511511ec2b5a"},registered:{date:"2016-04-10T14:57:49.011Z",age:6}}],info:{seed:"foobar",results:10,page:1,version:"1.3"}},{results:[{gender:"female",name:{title:"Miss",first:"Avery",last:"Harris"},email:"avery.harris@example.com",login:{uuid:"36213f8d-ab68-4906-b215-5660c84ffbf2",username:"greengoose482",password:"amazon",salt:"SAFLaz7k",md5:"99b57bab46e91f99e28f9920a70789db",sha1:"ed0faee69842302e732f92f6d06f44d97f3c617e",sha256:"ebcccbab0ce22a2ee5f5caa0f88abbbc58e1fc89829bf30ebfe81b839c0aca1a"},registered:{date:"2002-05-16T09:53:41.802Z",age:20}},{gender:"male",name:{title:"Mr",first:"Milton",last:"Miles"},email:"milton.miles@example.com",login:{uuid:"b16bf03e-daa8-46b9-8c8c-6fe605abaa63",username:"brownpanda533",password:"gggg",salt:"4zdtNQQO",md5:"5415ef33797665bc91103cc28e10c127",sha1:"00816e03d999d456524abf9a3f1229d930c2ca37",sha256:"da3db1d7fe779b4c2c5ceebefa60c43a2d5eacb0a31ed8305b52859db82a100d"},registered:{date:"2012-02-11T18:46:12.048Z",age:10}}],info:{seed:"foobar",results:10,page:2,version:"1.3"}}];

const allUsers = users.flatMap(({ results }) => results);
const femaleOrMilUsers = allUsers.filter(u => u.email.startsWith('mil') || u.gender === 'female');
console.log(femaleOrMilUsers);
```

If you want to change the existing structure, and mutate the results array so that only the matching users are included, iterate over each object in the outer array and reassign the `results` property to the filtered array.

```js
let users=[{results:[{gender:"female",name:{title:"Miss",first:"Britney",last:"Sims"},email:"britney.sims@example.com",login:{uuid:"2d5afd5e-a598-469f-9933-4edba18bcefb",username:"blueelephant921",password:"ccccccc",salt:"uJHyJ9ZL",md5:"5724c4fbd97e5155d19f71a44f12cc48",sha1:"85dff52890cee9977409fc6ae332a7e2326d6aa4",sha256:"ab62d511f943bfca48935cb4620b3b2007f8d1b9c1e04a04ea76ea95cd099d5f"},registered:{date:"2014-05-20T20:54:39.692Z",age:8}},{gender:"female",name:{title:"Ms",first:"Imogen",last:"Edwards"},email:"imogen.edwards@example.com",login:{uuid:"5a79ebec-08a6-45de-a2de-b3222f0d1ffe",username:"silversnake277",password:"clifford",salt:"7d1g093S",md5:"585e4a480fb97e0f7430ace6acaabd4f",sha1:"c2214f29692ca2aea5898f7c9e40846e125c5657",sha256:"6ec460f8cbc394e7758f22bbe185c5ae54048e1924fad1b94ac2511511ec2b5a"},registered:{date:"2016-04-10T14:57:49.011Z",age:6}}],info:{seed:"foobar",results:10,page:1,version:"1.3"}},{results:[{gender:"female",name:{title:"Miss",first:"Avery",last:"Harris"},email:"avery.harris@example.com",login:{uuid:"36213f8d-ab68-4906-b215-5660c84ffbf2",username:"greengoose482",password:"amazon",salt:"SAFLaz7k",md5:"99b57bab46e91f99e28f9920a70789db",sha1:"ed0faee69842302e732f92f6d06f44d97f3c617e",sha256:"ebcccbab0ce22a2ee5f5caa0f88abbbc58e1fc89829bf30ebfe81b839c0aca1a"},registered:{date:"2002-05-16T09:53:41.802Z",age:20}},{gender:"male",name:{title:"Mr",first:"Milton",last:"Miles"},email:"milton.miles@example.com",login:{uuid:"b16bf03e-daa8-46b9-8c8c-6fe605abaa63",username:"brownpanda533",password:"gggg",salt:"4zdtNQQO",md5:"5415ef33797665bc91103cc28e10c127",sha1:"00816e03d999d456524abf9a3f1229d930c2ca37",sha256:"da3db1d7fe779b4c2c5ceebefa60c43a2d5eacb0a31ed8305b52859db82a100d"},registered:{date:"2012-02-11T18:46:12.048Z",age:10}}],info:{seed:"foobar",results:10,page:2,version:"1.3"}}];

for (const obj of users) {
  obj.results = obj.results.filter(u => u.email.startsWith('mil') || u.gender === 'female');
}
console.log(users);
```

Comment: It works. But I still want the data structure not to change. I want the structure like the above. How?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Your question said that you wanted users for which the email or the gender matches. This retrieves such users.

Comment: I added my expected result into your previous comment.